# jQuery multiple toggle hide all / show only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Dear Programmers,

I have a header menu, with "Search", "Language", "Time" toggle functions.

Regarding display onClick it works correctly, but I need If I Click on "Search" show only "Search" and hide all "Language", "Time".

My code

.js

```
$( '.search-toggle' ).on( 'click.twentyfourteen', function( event ) {
        var that    = $( this ),
            wrapper = $( '.search-box-wrapper' );

        that.toggleClass( 'active' );
        wrapper.toggleClass( 'hide' );

        if ( that.is( '.active' ) || $( '.search-toggle .screen-reader-text' )[0] === event.target ) {
            wrapper.find( '.search-field' ).focus();
        }
    } );  

    $( '.language-toggle' ).on( 'click.twentyfourteenn', function( event ) {
        var that    = $( this ),
            wrapper = $( '.language-box-wrapper' );

        that.toggleClass( 'active' );
        wrapper.toggleClass( 'hide' );

} );     

        $( '.time-toggle' ).on( 'click.twentyfourteennn', function( event ) {
        var that    = $( this ),
            wrapper = $( '.time-box-wrapper' );

        that.toggleClass( 'active' );
        wrapper.toggleClass( 'hide' );

} );
```

and html

```
<div class="search-toggle">
            <a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
        </div>
  
        <div class="language-toggle">
            <a href="#language-container" class="language-screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyfourteenn' ); ?></a>
        </div>
  
  <div class="time-toggle">
            <a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyfourteennn' ); ?></a>
        </div>

    <div id="search-container" class="search-box-wrapper hide">
        <div class="search-box">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>   

        <div id="language-container" class="language-box-wrapper hide">
        <div class="language-box">
        language
        </div>
    </div> 

            <div id="time-container" class="time-box-wrapper hide">
        <div class="time-box">
        time
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean you want to hide two different elements when clicking search you want the others to hide?

By using add you can group elements together then add classes to show or hide:

```
$('#element1_id').add('#element2_id').removeClass('show');
$('#element1_id').add('#element2_id').addClass('hide');
```

or just straight up hide them with jQuery.

```
$('#element1_id').add('#element2_id').hide();
```

You could also give the element you want to hide together a common class name:

ie: toggle

then you can simply use the class toggle to hide them:

```
$('.toggle').removeClass('show');
$('.toggle').addClass('hide');
```

or

```
$('.toggle').hide();
```

Comment: Hello, please could you add this into my .js code ? If I click on "1" display me content, If I click on "2" display content but "1" is still show, I need hide "1"

Answer (score 0):

i think this will hide other parts, i have not tried this but hope will work for u

```
$( '.search-toggle' ).on( 'click.twentyfourteen', function( event ) {
        var that    = $( this ),
            wrapper = $( '.search-box-wrapper' );

        that.toggleClass( 'active' );
        $( '.search-box-wrapper' ).hide();
$( '.time-box-wrapper' ).hide();
$( '.language-box-wrapper' ).hide();
        if ( that.is( '.active' ) || $( '.search-toggle .screen-reader-text' )[0] === event.target ) {
            wrapper.find( '.search-field' ).focus();
        }
    } );  

    $( '.language-toggle' ).on( 'click.twentyfourteenn', function( event ) {
        var that    = $( this ),
            wrapper = $( '.language-box-wrapper' );

   $( '.search-box-wrapper' ).hide();
$( '.time-box-wrapper' ).hide();
$( '.language-box-wrapper' ).hide();
        that.toggleClass( 'active' );


} );     

        $( '.time-toggle' ).on( 'click.twentyfourteennn', function( event ) {
        var that    = $( this ),
            wrapper = $( '.time-box-wrapper' );
 $( '.search-box-wrapper' ).hide();
$( '.time-box-wrapper' ).hide();
$( '.language-box-wrapper' ).hide();
        that.toggleClass( 'active' );


} );
```

Comment: Hello Sachin Loonia, thank you for your answer and your time, but still not work for me. I think that we need add something what you post, but with better way..

If I click on Search, Search content show me, It´s OK!

But If I click on Language, Language content show me, but still show me too Search content.. and I need hide this content and apply this rule for all options.. that still will be show only one content If user click through this..

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem. You can view working demo with this link *[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S55ab/)*

**Summary of what I did.**

- I added some text as link in the html (just for testing)
- I added `.hide()` Jquery class to hide the three wrapper classes before the click events
- I added a little bit of animation to `wrapper.toggle('slow')`
- I changed `wrapper.toggleClass('slow')` to `wrapper.toggle('slow')`

  $('.search-box-wrapper').hide();
      $('.language-box-wrapper').hide();
      $('.time-box-wrapper').hide();

  ```
  $('.search-toggle').on('click.SearchLink', function (event) {
      var that = $(this),
          wrapper = $('.search-box-wrapper');
      that.toggleClass('active');
      wrapper.toggle('slow');

      if (that.is('.active') || $('.search-toggle .screen-reader-text')[0] === event.target) {
          wrapper.find('.search-field').focus();
      }
  });

  $('.language-toggle').on('click.LangLink', function (event) {
      var that = $(this),
          wrapper = $('.language-box-wrapper');
      that.toggleClass('active');
      wrapper.toggle('slow');

  });

  $('.time-toggle').on('click.TimeLink', function (event) {
      var that = $(this),
          wrapper = $('.time-box-wrapper');
      that.toggleClass('active');
      wrapper.toggle('hide');
  });
  ```